# Qual é a origem de «pelota»?

Tags: etimologia

No Minho, norte de Portugal era usual dizer-se «andar em [pelota](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pelota)» que quer dizer "andar sem roupa", "nu".

> em pelota • [Informal]  Sem roupa (ex.: andar em pelota). = EM PÊLO,
>   EM PELOTE, NU
>
> "pelota", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pelota [consultado em
>   01-08-2017].

Qual é a origem desta palavra?

Comment: Muito interessante! Pelota em espanhol é bola e usado em algumas regiões no sul do Brasil pela influência do Uruguai e Argentina. Mas nunca tinha visto essa definição.

Answer (score 3):

Na Argentina e outros países latinoamericanos, assim como na Espanha, a expressão *en pelota(s)* (*andar ~, ir ~, estar ~*, etc.) é usada com o mesmo significado. Na Argentina pelo menos *pelotas* é um sinônimo coloquial/vulgar de *testículos* (também *bolas*), e eu sempre tinha relacionado esse uso com a expressão *en pelota(s)*, ainda que seja aplicada também a mulheres, mas essa é uma interpretação posterior (um reanálise). Segundo a Wikipédia em espanhol, [en pelota](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_pelota) vem

> da expressão medieval *en pellote*, "ir vestido em roupa de casa" ou, mas específicamente, com o *pellón*, *pellote* ou *pelote*...

que até o século XVII significava só isso ("meio vestido, vestido com roupa de casa que a gente não usa para sair em público"), mas já no s. XVIII passa a significar "nu", "sem roupa", e no s. XIX é reanalizada como *en pelotas* e fica relacionada às *pelotas* masculinas (os testículos).

Daí devo supor que o desenvolvimento da expressão foi aproximadamente o mesmo em português.

Comment: Aparentemente o  filólogo Juan Corominas não liga *en pelota* a *pellote*. Diz no Houaiss que Corominas vê *en pelota* como possível influência de *pelo* ou *pele*. Andei a ver no Cordes, e já no sXVI se usava em castelhano *en pelo* com o significado de 'nu'.

Answer (score 0):

Só para acrescentar à resposta do pablodf76 que provavelmente teve origem no Latin Vulgar onde *pila* [significa bola](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/pila#Substantivo_9), e o [diminutivo correspondente](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pelote#French) é *pilotta*.

Possivelmente por associação aos testículos (ou de andar com eles expostos) veio a significar andar nú.